# How to specify SIDs in Security Policy?

Tags: windows, security, permissions, ntfs, windows-server-2012-r2

After the installation of KB2871997, on Windows Server 2008 R2 on a domain controller, you get a new user group: 'Restricted Users', and as [this article mentions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2014/06/05/an-overview-of-kb2871997.aspx), you get two new well known SIDs:

1. **LOCAL_ACCOUNT** – Any local account will inherit this SID
2. **LOCAL_ACCOUNT_AND_MEMBER_OF_ADMINISTRATORS_GROUP** – Any local account that is a member of the administrators group will inherit this SID

This [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab) lists out all well known SIDs, and the same page lists these two new SIDs (**S-1-5-113**, and **S-1-5-114**). In Windows header, RIDs for these are included:

```
#define SECURITY_LOCAL_ACCOUNT_RID (0x00000071L) // 113
#define SECURITY_LOCAL_ACCOUNT_AND_ADMIN_RID (0x00000072L) / 114
```

I have discovered the importance of Restricted Users group, but couldn't understand how these SIDs can be placed under Security of any object - starting with file/folder on NTFS drive, how to give these (or any) SIDs?

I am doing this research to see any impact of this update on any application or service, due to possible restriction placed on top of these.

Thanks to **grawity** for providing example using `icacls`. After fiddling around with security UI and `icacls` itself, I have found out that there are many SIDs which cannot be directly specified with friendly name, **but** will appear in results. That means on Security dialog box, as well as when `icacls` is called. Try this (on any recent OS):

```
icacls FolderName /grant:*S-1-18-2:(oi)(ci)(f)
```

Followed by following command:

```
icacls Folder name
```

You will see '*Service asserted identity*' in command output, and in Security dialog box. For the new SIDs, you wont see it when you specify `/save` along with above' command. You will however see it in Security dialog box. In short, there is little inconsistently.

So, ***now***, my question is: How to specify SID in Security Policy ?

Answer (score 2):

For files, you can use the `icacls` tool to add access entries by SID:

```
icacls C:\Temp /grant *S-1-5-113:(oi)(ci)(f)
```

Though, using the full name `NT AUTHORITY\Local account` should work as well.

Comment: Thanks for sample. It works for folder, but not for files. It worked for S-1-5-113 SID also, and Explorer shows 'Local account'. Why it doesn't allow it to input using text? Yes, I have used the full name as you suggested, but no.

Comment: @Everyone - After you give above' command. Then try following commands: 'icacls C:\Temp' and 'icacls c:\Temp /save acl.txt'. You will see that former displays 'Local account', but latter stores 'S-1-5-113'. Definitely a bug in OS.

Comment: @Ajay: If `/save` stores the SID, it sounds like a _feature_ to me. The names are just for convenience; the ACL doesn't actually store them.

Comment: yes it stores the SID for the accounts it doesn't understand. Try it yourself on 2012R2 or 8.1! BTW, I am still fiddling with "How to specify SID in Object Picker security dialog box".